# Coxeter graph of the group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \dots \times \mathbb{Z}_2$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, reflection, combinatorial-group-theory, coxeter-groups

I am reading the first chapter of *Combinatorics of Coxeter Groups* by A.Björner and F.Brenti. In the first example they say that the graph with $n$ isolated vertices (no edges) is the Coxeter graph of the group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \dots \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ of order $2^n$. I just want to make sure that I understand this statement correctly. Let us consider an example. Let $S=\{1,2,3\}$ and the corresponding matrix $m: S \times S \rightarrow \{1,2,\dots,\infty \}$ be 
    \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 2\\
2 & 1 & 2\\
2 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
Then the corresponding Coxeter graph is just $3$ isolated vertices. Moreover $m$ determines a group with a presentation: \begin{equation}
\langle s_1,s_2,s_3|s_1^2=s_2^2=s_3^2=e,s_1s_2=s_2s_1,s_1s_3=s_3s_1,s_2s_3=s_3s_2\rangle
\end{equation}
and that is just $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$. Is that what they mean?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. More generally, the connected components of the Coxeter diagram associated to a direct product of groups are the Coxeter diagrams associated to the factors.

Comment: Ok, great, thank you @pregunton